# The error message from Yup's custom validation doesn't disappear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I want to check for any duplicate email as part of the signing up process using a custom validation from `Yup`:

```js
validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
    email: yup
        .string()
        .email()
        .test({
            name: 'duplicate-email-check',
            params: 'value',
            message: 'Duplicate email already exists',
            test: async (value) => {
                firebase
                    .auth()
                    .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(value)
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result === "password") {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
        })
        .required(),
})}
```

I'm using [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetch-sign-inmethods-for-email) to fetch any kind of accounts with the same email and if it exists, a validation error message will be thrown. I'm modeling after the [mixed().text()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetch-sign-inmethods-for-email) schema, but the problem is the error message "Duplicate email already exists" doesn't disappear once it shows up even though there is no duplicate email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code does not return a Promise which return a boolean for `test`

```js
test: async (value) => { // Notice this, adding curly braces will require you to put a return statement
                firebase
                    .auth()
                    .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(value)
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result === "password") {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
```

You can change the code to:

```js
test: async (value) => { // Notice this, adding curly braces will require you to put a return statement
                return firebase // Notice I added the return statement
                    .auth()
                    .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(value)
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result === "password") {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
```